# Angularjs filter allow null value using custom comparator not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## [Revised] I find out a solution to deal with that, just use AngularJs with ver. >= 1.3.6, items with null property will not be dropped after applying a filter and cancel it!!

### *following is original question*

Hi, all. im using AngularJs to display data in a table with ng-repeat directive, and a textbox to filter "Color" property of cats. notice that some cat has null Color property.

Once i type some text in the textbox and clear it, all cat with color property is null are gone.

I set a custom comparator returning true on `expected === ''`, but it doesn't work. actually, all cat with color `property === null` will never shown once the searching textbox has been placed some text into and been cleared afterward even i let the comparator always return true.

Is there any way to allow null values when using a filter in ng-repeat? thank you inadvance!!

JS Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLL7wvcL/2/

my data(array of cats)

```
$scope.cats = [
{'Name': 'John',
 'Sex': 'Male',
 'Color': 'Black'},
{'Name': 'Rose',
 'Sex': 'Female',
 'Color': 'White'},
  {'Name': 'Cindy',
 'Sex': 'Female',
 'Color': 'Yellow'},
  {'Name': 'David',
 'Sex': 'Male',
 'Color': 'Black'},
  {'Name': 'Garen',
 'Sex': 'Male',
 'Color': null},
  {'Name': 'Jim',
 'Sex': 'Male',
 'Color': null},
  {'Name': 'Charotte',
 'Sex': 'Female',
 'Color': 'Black'}
];
```

and both comparator following not working, once the searching textbox has been placed some text into and been cleared afterward, all cat with color property === null will never shown.

```
$scope.myComparator = function (actual, expected) 
  {
      if (expected === '') 
          return true;
      else
      {
          var text = ('' + actual).toLowerCase();
            return text.indexOf(expected) > -1;
      }
  };

$scope.myComparator = function (actual, expected) 
  {
      return true;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that after you clear the input, filter model looks like this:

```
{"Color": ""}
```

so empty string will not match colors with color `null`. What you just need to do is to remove "Color" property if it's `null`, maybe on change. In this case you will not need `myComparator` at all:

```
$scope.clear = function() {
    if ($scope.search.Color === null) {
        delete $scope.search.Color;
    }
};
```

and you would use just

```
ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter:search"
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/MrvBa09y9SrE3TlTUxP6?p=preview

Comment: thanks! it works! But i think this way is kind of a workaround? If i want filter more than one property, i have to write more delete statement in clear() function, right? I really curious about why the comparator always returning true still blocks items with null property

Comment: *"I really curious about why the comparator always returning true still blocks items with null property"* comparator is not even called for null values, because it's executed after filter function (previous step). And filter expression excludes `Color: null` objects.

Comment: *"If i want filter more than one property, i have to write more delete statement in clear() function, right?"* you can write generic function, like in this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/PEGJMdenU9CtfOd1vaID?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to use a filter function, compare against the entire object rather than the property and attach the criteria to the controller scope.

**Markup:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="cat in cats | filter:myComparator">
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.myComparator = function (actual) 
{
    var expected = $scope.filter;
    if (expected === '') 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        var text = ('' + actual.Color).toLowerCase();
        return text.indexOf(expected) > -1;
    }
};
```

Full example in an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLL7wvcL/3/

Comment: Thank you, it works!  but with this solution, i must hard-code `var expected = $scope.filter;` to get my expected value.

Answer (score -1):

if (expected === '')  will check for empty string, not null.

Try replacing it with

if (!expected)
    .....

Comment: The expected is the input string to search against which will indeed be '' when there is no search value.

Comment: thanks for answer!! but i think the "expected" means what's inside my searching textbox, not the actual value of my data being filtered. i tried your solution, and it's sadly not working, too.